# Powershell - rerun the script with different credentials from itself

Tags: powershell

I have currently had to take a huge leap from my unix scripting to the MS side of things and found myself overwhelmed with PowerShell.

My situation is as follows:
I have a script `script.ps1` which can be only run under specific windows account. In order to facilitate the use, it was decided that if user runs the script from a different account, it will pop up a query for credentials and restart itself from within (similarly to recursion), but importantly - maintaining the input parameters.

I have found out, that the `Invoke-Command` is probably what I am looking for, but I cannot seem to be able to build the PS query for this.

my code snippet looks like

```
if(!([System.Environment]::UserName -eq $user)){
$Credential = Get-Credential -credential INTRANET\$user
Invoke-Command -FilePath $script -Credential $Credential -ArgumentList $arguments
}
```

where $user contains the desired user, $script contains filepath to the `script.ps1` and $arguments contain command line arguments that were passed to the script as a String, i. e. `-order 66 -location UAT`

but currently I get an error

```
Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
...
FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet
```

I tried shuffling the parameters around, I tried using Start-Process instead of Invoke-Command, but everything resulted in same or similar errors.

Also, because I am really new to the powershell, please do not hesitate to offer different solution, if it is viable. I do not know the capabilities of the language well.

Lastly, please note that the starting point is always powershell prompt running with non-elevated user account. Unfortunately, the option to start up powershell under a different account in the first place is not available to us.

Comment: Does your script has accept those arguments as parameters when you just run it normally? e.g. `.\myscript.ps1 argument1 argument 2`. See https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/how-to-use-parameters-in-powershell/

Comment: Yes, yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably is that you specify the parameters stored in the variable `$arguments` as string in the regular format like you said: `-order 66 -location UAT`

The parameter `-ArgumentList` works differently, its an array used for array splatting. So you can't pass the values by the parameter name. You have to pass the values by parameter order, e.g.:

```
$Arguments = @(66,'uat')
Invoke-Command -FilePath $script -Credential $Credential -ArgumentList $Arguments
```

See Parameter [Argumentlist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2).
See [Array Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2#splatting-with-arrays).

The value `66` is passed to the first parameter, the value `uat` to the 2nd... So you must know the order of the parameters and insert the related values into the array at the right position.

To control the position of the parameters, the param specification in the other script should at least have:

```
param (
    [parameter(Position=1)]
    [int]$order,
    [parameter(Position=2)]
    [string]$location
)
```

Comment: Is there any way how to retain the user friendly option to use named parameters (other than parsing it myself manually)? I could not find any in the materials, but it feels like a big oversight

Comment: without modification of the current scripts in combination with invoke-command the answer is NO. sure its possible with scriptblock/$using but to achieve that is more complex than to prepare an array the right way for the parameter -argumentlist.